# How do I import Encrypted ZMK.LMK into HSM for triple DES operations?

Tags: hsm

I'm trying to import the ZMK that encrypted with LMK into HSM Thales 9000 for triple DES operations.
anyone had any idea for it ?

the ZMK is form by 3 clear component and encrypted under LMK. And i didnt have the 3 clear component.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your only way to import this key is either with the 3 components or use the same LMK.

if you have imported the 3 components on the same device or you are using the same LMK (on multiple devices) you can just use the encrypted ZMK whenever needed.

what are you trying to do?

Comment: hi Yarix. i want to use the ZMK.LMK to do the 3Des decryption, do you know what host command code for the 3Des decryption ?

Comment: You want to do decryption via HSM Console Command or HSM Host Command?

Comment: hi, i'm not sure i understand what you need. were you able to import the ZMK? if not. and you have the encrypted components, you can use A4 host command to Form a Key from Encrypted Components.

Comment: if you just try to encrypt a block of data, you can use M0 host command (but you'll need a Zone/Terminal encryption key ZEK/TEK)

Comment: hi @Yarix , just got the key components, so able to generate the clear ZMK for encryption.
thank you.